# What can I do with my locked iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sim, cellular-carriers

I bought an iPhone4 from ebay, and it was marked as UNLOCKED, but in fact it was not.. After couple of emails, I gave this up, and I want to sell it. It is AT&T. The questions are:

1) What would you do in my case? The untethered jailbreak came out, but needs iPhone to be activated. iOS was upgraded to 5.1.1 9B206, so also the baseband is quite new - no way to unlock it in the near future.

2) iPhone must be activated with the original AT&T SIM or just any AT&T SIM ? So that, I could write it in description in case I would sell it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your questions:

1. <s>I haven't tested it myself (but I'll in the near future), but there are [SIM](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Unlock-iPhone-4S-9B206-iOS-5-1-1-2-0-12-Baseband-R-SIM-3-III-Ultra-NO-112-Deal-/380440945395?pt=SIM_Cards&hash=item58940c22f3) cards available, comparable to the Gravy SIM (but here is no need to dial 112), which will unlock your iPhone. It's not that expensive, so I would give it a try.</s>
   Sorry, it looks like this SIM only supports the iPhone 4S.
2. You can unlock the iPhone with any AT&T card, no need for the original card. At least, that worked with my T-Mobile locked iPhone. So I would guess it's the same for your AT&T locked iPhone.

Do you know you have a return policy on eBay? And in a matter of fact, if you've paid with PayPal, you can set-up a conflict and ask for your money back... But this just for your information.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The thing is, I bought it half a year ago, and it worked fine with Gevey SIM. But as I updated the iOS, Gevey SIM does not work. So it's already late to contact ebay.